# How do I create Keyboard shortcuts for operations in a website on OS X?

Tags: keyboard, websites, smart-keyboard

I need someone to help me out in assigning Keyboard shortcuts for a few operations/tabs on a website in Mac. I'm working on a website that plays the audio files. So, I want to create a Keyboard Shortcut for the play button listed on that website so that I can avoid using the mouse as I continuously love to work only with Keyboard.

Eg: Spacebar for Play/pause on Youtube.com

Comment: Are you looking for ways to configure Safari, for ways on how to develop a site with keyboard shortcuts, or something else? Please *edit* your question to clarify, and add some specific examples and what you have tried already to solve the problem.

Comment: I use keyboard maestro as my keyboard manager.

Comment: @historystamp So, I want to map the play/pause button on a website to a custom Keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I already have a website that plays the audio files and I need to develop a Keyboard shortcut that should be mapped to the "play/pause" radio button on the webpage.

Comment: Do you own the website?  If you do, you can add some javascript to the web site to look for a command key which when found plays the audio. If you do not own the site, I do not know an easy way.  The only thing that I can think of is to inject some javascript into the web site.

Comment: This belongs in the web apps or webmasters forum.  Nothing really to do with Apple.

Comment: What OS and version are you using? What Web Browser are you using? What is the URL of the website?

Comment: @Tom Gewecke, RE: "This belongs in the web apps or webmasters forum. Nothing really to do with Apple. "... While the question and tags have not clearly indicated this has to do with macOS, nonetheless, nohillside asked in a comment "Are you looking for ways to configure Safari.." to which the author of the post replied "Yes, ..." so from that I'd say for now this question belongs on this site, however I have asked for clarification in my previous comment. So lets wait and see the response to those questions before a determination is made as to whether or not this question belongs on this site.

Comment: Indra sena, Have a look at: [How can I play/pause youtube player on its native site itself using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985828/how-can-i-play-pause-youtube-player-on-its-native-site-itself-using-javascript)

Comment: @user3439894 Mac OS, Safari. I'm really sorry, I couldn't reveal the website. It's a website owned by an individual which play songs/audio files. I want to create an extension or app which only works in safari or that particular website so that I can click the 'Play' Radio button using a keyboard shortcut rather than hovering my mouse and clicking.

Comment: Could you create a single-site browser for that site using something like https://fluidapp.com ? If so, you could then assign keyboard shortcuts to that app using Keyboard Maestro or some such.

Comment: This still seems like a programming question that belongs elsewhere -- in stack overflow if not in the forums for creating web sites or web apps.